# How to fetch and store data in database of Joomla 1.7?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I am learning Joomla. I have installed 1.7 and I don't understand how to store the data in the database.

I was going through [this link](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Joomla-Component-Registering-Your-Component-in-database-P36.html)  and then I realized that this is for 1.5 as 1.7 doesn't has (prefix)_components in Joomla database.

How do I do this with 1.7? I need to store and fetch the data from the database. I can construct queries for this, but don't understand where I insert my queries.

Comment: I just want to know that where i can write my queries to get the result. Please somebody help me in this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to start with the [Joomla Developer Documentation here](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know the MVC architecture of joomla.Then,try to create simple component for joomla by reading the following link

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5

This link also some what useful for you

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script